# Elastic search, having should inside of should

Tags: elasticsearch

I am searching throught logs with wildcards on multiple fields ,these wildcard queries are inside a should class, every log aside the fields that I search with wildcards is having a "action_id" field, I want to return only the logs that are matching one or more of wildcards and have one or more of the action_id's that I want(A or B in the example).

**What doesnt work:**

```
    q={
        "size" : 20,
        "sort" : [
            { "clsfd_id" : {"order" : "asc"}},
        ],
        "fields":
        "query":{  
           "filtered":{  
              "query":{  
                 "match_all":{  

                 }
              },
              "filter":{  
                 "bool":{  
                    "should":[  
                       {  
                          "query":{  
                             "term":{  
                                "id":"*12*"
                             }
                          }}                  #gets filled dynamically with wildcard queries
                       ],
                       "should":[  
                          {"query":{  
                             "term":{  
                                "action_id":"A"
                             }
                            }
                          },
                          {"query":{  
                             "term":{  
                                "action_id":"B"
                             }
                            }
                          },
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
        }
    }
```

**Example doc:**

```
{
  "_index": "logs",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "AVdPQBuRkYFjD-WA9CiE",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "username": "Ιδιώτης",
    "user_id": null,
    "action_on": "Part",
    "ip": "sensitive info",
    "idents": [
      "sensiti",
      "sensitive info"
    ],
    "time": "2016-09-21T19:18:11.184576",
    "id": 5993765,
    "changes": "bla bla bla",
    "action_id": "A"
  }
```

*This is Elastic 1.7 by the way

Comment: can you post an example doc?

Comment: @jay , check it out

Answer (score 0):

"I want to return only the logs that are matching the wildcards"

Shouldn't it then be in a `must` clause instead of `should`? Also [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) can take multiple term candidates so you don't need to create separate filters for `action_id` A and B. When reading docs note that query DSL has changed quite a lot between 1.x and 2.x versions of Elastisearch, filters and queries have been more or less "merged" together.

Edit: Based on the comment, this should work assuming the original query was functional (sorry too lazy to test it):

```
{
    "size": 20,
    "sort": [{"clsfd_id" : {"order" : "asc"}}],
    "query":{
       "filtered":{
          "query":{"match_all":{}},
          "filter":{
             "bool":{
                "should":[
                   {
                      "query":{
                         "term": {"id":"*12*"}
                      }
                   },
                   {
                      "query":{
                         "term": {"id":"*23*"}
                      }
                   }
                ],
                "must":[
                   {
                       "query":{
                         "term": {"action_id": ["A", "B"]}
                      }
                   }
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

The more verbose option is to create a new "query => filtered => filter => should => terms" instead of the multi-term filter.

Comment: No , I meant that match atleast 1 of the wildcards plus  the action_id is either A or B or both, I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
{
"size" : 20,
"sort" : [{
        "date" : {
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
],
"fields" : [],
"query" : {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "wildcard" : {
                "id" : {
                    "value" : "*12*"
                }
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : {
                "action_id" : ["A", "B"]

            }
        }
    }
} }
```